# Backup of Einstein Bot

Tags: einstein, bots, backup, einstein-chatbot

Is there anyway to make a Backup of Einstein Bot and put it on Github or another place? An example is Metadata API or anything like that can download the Einstein Bot?
We will lose the Bots Licenses in Salesforce for a period but we have one project of it and we want to resume it after this period ends, may you help me informing if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this myself as I don't use Bots, but there's a metadata type for it so you should be able to pull what you want and store it somewhere.

In VS Code, you can pull the [Bot metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_bot.htm) with the [force:source:retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm) command

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Bot
```

And then push that to a repository of your choice (github, etc).

There's some related metadata I don't believe you necessarily need to pull but I'll mention anyway:

1. [BotSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_botsettings.htm) - this only seems to store whether it's enabled or not. Need to pull Settings.
2. [BotVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_botversion.htm) - The Bot metdata above only contains the active/specific version. If you want prior iterations you can pull this as well.